# Eloquent inheritance

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm designing a database with Eloquent/Laravel and I'm wondering whether the following is a best practise.

For the Cars table some columns are specific to the type of the car (load box dimensions) and some are common to all cars (color).

Is it OK if I have one table with some columns empty depending on the type or is it better to have different table per car type? If so, how to properly implement inheritance on the database level? I tried to find in documentation but the only reference is to polymorphic relations which is something different

Comment: Polymorphic is what you want. You'd have some table like attributes with an id and a type. If id was 1 and type was engine, you'd look in the engine table for id 1, if it was 1 and type was transmission, you'd look in the transmission table for id 1. Oh wait, you're saying per car type? I guess I'd want to see more examples of what you're trying to do. Would one car have colors and another would not?

Answer (score 1):

A simple pivot table should help you here. This helps you keep the common parameters with the car directly and to define specific types of car so that you can reuse the type with multiple cars. Sample structure to help you understand.

```
Car
- id
- name
- cost
- color

Type
- id
- size
- weight

Car_type
- car_id
- type_id
```

For example if you have car with spec **xyz**, and you can have this car in many colors. The above would allow for you to add multiple cars with different colors and use a single car type which contains the spec **xyz**.